# How to generate flow diagram from ASP.Net and C#.Net code?

Tags: c#, asp.net, uml, flow-diagram

I have started working on a new project and the code is huge. Documentation for that project is out of date. But i need to understand the code. One way is that i can put break point and debug the code to understand it but since code is huge and it may take about a month to understand in that way. What else or other faster approach i can use to understand the code something like creating its flow diagram from code?

Comment: You could use [ndepend](http://www.ndepend.com/) to find out the dependencies between classes or assemblies.

Comment: Thanks. But this tool is not freeware can you tell me something that's freeware.

Comment: @Balraj: would free trial wont serve the purpose?[link](http://www.ndepend.com/NDependDownload.aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're lucky enough to be using VS 2010 Ultimate then you can generate sequence diagrams simply by right-clicking a method and choosing "Generate Sequence Diagram...", there is a post [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2009/11/20/visual-studio-2010-generating-sequence-diagrams-on-the-fly.aspx) with an example.

You'll need Ultimate because you need UML support which is only in Ultimate edition.

Answer (score 2):

I remember doing this for Python last year and found it to be very usefull to understand the code layout (note: not the flow of exececution) but I believe this will give you a good start when you have lot of classes lying around undocumented. The end result is somewhat similar to javadocs.

they also do this for C#. Hope this helps

http://www.doxygen.nl

an example of its usage (generated on c++) can be found at
http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/apiDocs-3/hierarchy.html

**EDIT**: This is free, but I believe its worth some donation if it helped :)