# show what happened in particular method in visual studio 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uml

I'm developing an application that have some complexities on methods. Now I need a structure which can save what did I do in methods with shapes or something like this (i.e. `sequence diagram`).

Sequence diagram of visual studio do it with full detail which I don't need all of them, just some of them.

In the other hand I need something that can help other developers to understand my codes or methods easily and develop it. How can I do this?

Comment: write unit tests, and integration tests. It shows how code is meant to be used, and how it is composed.

Comment: BTW: if a method is more than approx. 25 lines, it is possible it is doing too much.

Comment: OK, I got it. You know, I wanna something help me for analyzing what did I do in method step by step. I haven't done test integration so I have problem with it.

Comment: NDepend has a 14 day trial. http://ndepend.com/

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to generate flow diagram from ASP.Net and C#.Net code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9410767/how-to-generate-flow-diagram-from-asp-net-and-c-net-code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you hesitate to do the testing, try this: install a helper tool like JetBrains [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) and safely refactor your code using the ["extract method"](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/code_refactoring.html#Extract_Method) command. Give them names that are easy to understand. Afterwards it might be easier for you to write unit tests as pointed out by the others in the comments.

I.e. rather put some effort in better methods than making others understand the mess.
It will also help you to produce much more meaningful sequence diagrams.

Disclaimer: Not affiliated with jetbrains.

Comment: Thanks. I think none of these will be help-fuller than Sequence Diagram. Thank you inform me about tool.